Can this be turned into an alter table function to remove the pulled duplicates?
SELECT 
  ride_id,
  rideable_type,
  started_at,
  ended_at,
  start_station_name,
  start_station_id,
  end_station_name, 
  start_lat, 
  start_lng, 
  end_lat,
  end_lng,
  member_casual
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ride_id,
    rideable_type,
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    start_station_name,
    start_station_id,
    end_station_name, 
    start_lat, 
    start_lng, 
    end_lat,
    end_lng,
    member_casual,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ride_id ORDER BY ride_id) AS row_num
 FROM `cyclistic-429604.yearly_csv.nu_null`
)

AS subquery
WHERE row_num > 1;

I have been trying to delete rows that only have a duplicate value in their ride_id. Can this query be used to delete the results? Is there an easier way to do this?
Thanks!

Should ride_id ideally always be unique? If yes do the duplicate instances have the same values in the other fields too? And yes is there any value in the table that DOES make the row unique, so you can match on that to remove the unwanted duplicates? You create a row_num but it is not present in the source table to match on it. You need something unique to match on. Without that will delete the wanted rows as well as the duplicates.

ALTERNATIVE 1: Select dupe ride_ids into a new or temp table, make unique, delete all ride_ids with dupes from the source table, reinsert the now-unique ride_ids.
ALTERNATIVE 2: SELECT DISTINCT data from the table into a new table, truncate the original table, reinsert the unique rows. Saves on having to deduplicate just the ride_ids with duplicates. BUT VERY RISKY if it goes wrong.
